# MATLAB Reversi Assistance

Tags: matlab

I have an assignment for which I need to remake the game [Reversi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi)/Othello in MATLAB using an 8x8 matrix where black is 1 and white is -1, and have a functional GUI.

I have been able to do the GUI etc, by myself, but when I reach the point where I need to allow for only valid moves, I become a little stuck.

I was curious if any of you would know of a way in which that could be done, because I've hit a road block. Essentially I need to scan all 8 directions of the matrix from the centre point, and find a valid combination of player_number*-1, in a row which end in a player_number (where player_number is the current players turn), but I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Each of the positions on the board use the regular positioning system of [i,j], and are found within the array game_state.

Comment: In terms of what I have tried myself, I was just hitting brick walls.
As for what I have done so far, would you like me to post what I have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming performance is not an issue, here is an algorithem:

```
For each empty gap
   for each direction
      move as long as you find your opponents stones
         if you found at least 1 opponent stone and you end up on your own stone
            then the current empty gap is a legal move
```

As for the directions, you simply need a list of the *changes in co-ordinates* that correspond to a move in each direction which, for example, might look something like this:

```
direction_left = [0; -1]; % zero rows, -1 columns
direction_up = ...;
direction_right = ...; 
... you fill in the rest
```

Then you can build the full list by concatenating these into a matrix of directions

```
directions = [direction_left direction_up ....]; % you fill in the rest
```

Of course, if this is used in multiple places in the code, you should build it into a function.

Comment: How would I go about doing the each direction label (including diagonals) and how would I go about doing the "move as long as you find your opponents stones" sections

Comment: By defining the directions and using a while loop.
Seriously, those things are fairly trivial so please try it yourself first.

Comment: While something may seem trivial to you, they may not be to some-one who was thrown head first into this language.

I realise now how to do the while loop, but I still am unsure how to define the direction.
Would the best manner be to tell it to search for the next in a vector in terms of [i,j] (i.e. for vertical searching look for [positioni - 1, positionj])

Comment: Well, think of a single case to illustrate: your matrix is 8x8; say your player is at location [3, 4] (row 3, column 4); you now want to move the player in the northeast direction (up and to the right). What will their new co-ordinates be?

Comment: Indeed follow the thoughts of @wakjah, the difference in coordinates will be your direction.

Comment: It would be [4,3], but I was curious if instead of having to make multiple different searchers in multiple lines, I could just put in functions saying UL (Up Left), DR (Down Right) etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I remember the rules of Reversi, but for what it's worth, here's a suggestion

```
currentPlayer = -1 ; % this should be either +1 or -1 depending on whose turn it is
board; % 8x8 matrix of 0 (unused) +/-1 (occupied positions)
candidateMovesMask = ( board == 0 ) & ( imdilate( board == -CurrentPlayer, true(3) ) );
[r c] = find( candidateMovesMask );
```

A short explaination:

```
imdilate( board == -CurrentPlayer, true(3) )
```

creates a binary mask with `true` next to each of the opponent's pieces. Intersecting this mask (using logical and `&`) with all vacant positions ( `board == 0` ) gives you a mask of all candidate moves.
Finally, `find( candidateMovesMask )` returns the row/column of each candidate move.

You still need to go through the candidate moves and find which one of them is indeed a legal move.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a start to finding moves next to pieces, the next step I need to hit though is whether or not it is a valid move in following the lines to having the correct sequence, is there any more I can do in regards to that?

Comment: This is a nice way to reduce the number of potential moves, unfortunately it won't gain you much for a 8x8 board (unlike the performance gain you might get on a 800x800 board).